# Is it possible to check user's moving activity when app is in background or killed in react native?

Tags: react-native, location, accelerometer, sensors

We are working on realtime location sharing app, we have to run our job's when app is in background and if its moving, we need to get the location of the user.

Is there any possibility in react-native so that we can track the user moving activity(in background and killed states) and track location or run the background job ?

Comment: I suggest [react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation](https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation) it is possible to keep location of users when app is running foreground or background.

Comment: yeah we used that, but the problem with that is our react native js code is not running when app killed or in background we don't have api's to send location to server (we are using firebase as backend), and that library is consuming more battery because of stay awake of device

Answer (score 2):

Try to listen for AppState changes and when your app goes in the background you should start doing what you want to do.

```
import { AppState } from 'react-native';
import BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-background-timer';


state = {
        appState: AppState.currentState
    }
```

In componentDidMount use this:

`AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);`

In componentWillUnmount :

`AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);`

Use something like this function and you will get your result for when the app is in the background.

```
_handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
        if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
            console.log('App has come to the foreground!');
        } else {
            console.log('App is in background');
            const interval = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {
                    console.log('listen for location changes here');
                    if (this.state.appState === 'active') {
                        //Stop the interval when AppState goes 
                        //back to active again
                        BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(interval);
                    }
                }, 1000);
          }
        }
        this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });
    }
```